# How do you deploy Graylog to an AWS Linux server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, graylog

I followed [these](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.3/pages/installation/aws.html) directions (graylog's website) to deploy Graylog to an Ubuntu server in AWS.  I created a server with 4 GB of RAM.

I created a security group that allows inbound connections on any TCP port from the external IP address of the Ubuntu server as well as from my desktop.

I opened a web browser and I went to the external IP address of the AWS instance with Graylog installed.  (I saw the services running on the back-end.)  I saw a picture associated with Graylog in the browser. But I saw "Server currently unavailable."  I saw this message where x.x.x.x was the internal IP address of the AWS Ubuntu server:

> Error message Request has been terminated Possible causes: the network
>   is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the
>   page is being unloaded, etc. Original Request GET
>   http://x.x.x.x:9000/api/system/sessions Status code undefined Full
>   error message Error: Request has been terminated Possible causes: the
>   network is offline, Origin is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.

I went to /var/log/graylog/server/.  But I saw nothing useful.  I rebooted the server.  I could never log into the web UI.  The services pop up automatically, and I can always see the picture and the error above.  This has never worked.  What did I do wrong?   How can I deploy Graylog to AWS?

Comment: What's the output of the following cURL command:
`curl -H 'Accept: application/json' 'http://x.x.x.x:9000/api/?pretty=true'`